# Rails 4 Select drop down not submitting values

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding

I have a form partial that almost everything uses and the arrays for two fields that I am generating the drop downs from live in the model.

```
<div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label 'Quantity', :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :quantity, :class => 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <%= error_span(@orders[:quantity]) %>
    </div>
```

This code works, the quantity class is usable and will update or populate on new order creation.

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label 'Model', :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <select name="model" class= 'form-control'>
      <%= Order::ORDER_MODELS.each do |model| %>
        <option value="<%= :model %>"><%= model %></option>
      <% end %>
    </select>
  </div>
```

This code does not work fine.  I can see all the values in the selector list, but it fails to populate when creating an order or when updating existing orders that were pre-loaded via CSV.

I have one other field that is a number_field that also works.  I have tried changing the value field from "<%= model %>" to the one it is at now, but I am not sure what is preventing this field from submitting.

how can I get the selector box to work with this form?  I don't have any form gems installed.  Is there some kind of f.select that I should be using instead of the way I am doing it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags).  You have a few options (pun intended) and they are covered pretty well here.  I would tend to pass the form builder `f` like `f.select(:model)...`. Also, make sure you are permitting any parameters you are collecting from your view in your controller.

Comment: Also, I have tried <%= f.select (:model, Order::ORDER_MODELS) %>, but that throws an error about the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPACES.  They get me every time.  <%= f.select (:model, Order::ORDER_MODELS) %> wasn't working because of the space before the (